# Having trouble debugging this jquery

Tags: jquery, debugging

O.K, the code's supposed to work like this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mjmitche/6nar4/  where any of the boxes on the left can be dropped into the boxes inside the black box.

On my live site, it's not working. If you go to this web address, and wait about 10 seconds a drop down menu will appear with a button "confirm" beside it. Click confirm and it will open a new page. The four boxes on the right of the new page are all draggable, and the four little boxes in the white box are all droppable. However, in actual fact, only the little red box--which is "#chair2" in the code below-- is droppable.  #chair1, #chair2, #chair3 are not accepting the drop.

[prupt.com](http://prupt.com)

This is the section of code that sets droppable and draggable

```
$(document).ready(function($) {    
$("#cloud1, #cloud2, #cloud3, #cloud4").draggable(); 
$("#chair1, #chair2, #chair3, #chair4").droppable({           
  accept: "#cloud1, #cloud2, #cloud3, #cloud4",  
  activeClass: "ui-state-hover",   
  hoverClass: "ui-state-active",      
   drop: function (event, ui) {  
   $(this)     
   .addClass ("ui-state-highlight")    
   .find ("p")    
   .html("dropped");          
 $("#topnav4").css({'background':'pink'}); 
             }      
      }); 
 });
```

This is all the jquery code from start to finish

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
$(init);   
}); 

function init() {
cloudshow();
}
function cloudshow() {
$("#intro").fadeIn(1000, function(){
    $("#intro2").fadeIn(1000, function(){
    $("#cloud1").fadeIn(2000, function(){
    $("#cloud2, #cloud5").fadeIn(2000, function(){
    $("#cloud3, #cloud4, #cloud6").fadeIn(2000, function(){
    $("#message").fadeIn(1000, function() {
    $("#contactform").fadeIn(1000)
    });  
    });

    });
    });
    });
});
};


var img1 = "url('/wp-content/themes/thesis_18/custom/images/map.jpg') repeat";
$(".submit").click(function(){
$("body.custom").css({background: img1});   
$("#topnav4, #cloud1, #cloud2, #cloud3, #cloud4, #cloud5, #cloud6, #intro, #intro2, #message, #contactform").fadeOut(1000, function (){
$("#sidenav").fadeIn(1000, function(){
        $("#topnav4").css({'background': 'none', 'display':'block'});
    $("#bigbox").fadeIn(1000, function(){
    $("#cloud1").css({'display':'block', 'position':'absolute','left':'600px', 'top': '50px', 'z-index': '2'});
        $("#cloud2").css({'display':'block', 'position':'absolute','left':'600px', 'top': '150px', 'z-index': '2'});    
    $("#cloud3").css({'display':'block', 'position':'absolute','left':'600px', 'top': '250px', 'z-index': '2'});
        $("#cloud4").css({'display':'block', 'position':'absolute','left':'600px', 'top': '350px', 'z-index': '2'});


    });
    });
     }); 
    });


$(document).ready(function($) {    
$("#cloud1, #cloud2, #cloud3, #cloud4").draggable(); 
$("#chair1, #chair2, #chair3, #chair4").droppable({           
  accept: "#cloud1, #cloud2, #cloud3, #cloud4",  
  activeClass: "ui-state-hover",   
  hoverClass: "ui-state-active",      
   drop: function (event, ui) {  
   $(this)     
   .addClass ("ui-state-highlight")    
   .find ("p")    
   .html("dropped");          
 $("#topnav4").css({'background':'pink'}); 
             }      
      }); 
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are including jQuery thrice on the page. In Firebug console, if you type jQuery.fn.draggable, you'll get undefined. It looks like including jQuery multiple times is causing this.

Comment: O.K, I see that I had it included one extra time, but now I think I only have jquery-ui and jquery included, but it still doesn't work. Do you still see jquery included an extra time? Is it possible that you mistook the jquery-ui for the third time?

Comment: @Michael, it's still present twice. Once in the header, added by WP core, and once by Thesis.

Comment: just to confirm, do you see the Google-hosted jquery and jquery ui?   Should I delete the folder then in WordPress?

Comment: I have this also included <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: If you look inside "container" inside "body.custom", there's also the Google hosted versions of jquery and jqueryui...Should they still function in that position?

Comment: @Michael, I see both jquery and jqueryui from Google, as well as jquery.js loaded from your own site (the WP default). You need to include jquery-ui in the header, otherwise your function won't work.

Comment: o.k, thanks, I put them in the wordpress head now, but I can't get rid of the js included by Wordpress, even though I deleted the folder.

Comment: can I pay you $10 to go into my Wordpress and figure out why the core jquery's still included?

Comment: sorry, I had to take away accepted answer because on a new site with only one installation of jquery, the same problem still exists.   Thank you for your help though. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608809/how-is-it-that-changing-positioning-on-css-can-affect-dropability-in-jquery